# SQL Server 2008 convert long and lat to x and y

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hopefully someone can help because I have been searching almost everywhere for an answer and still not satisfied.

I have X and Y coordinates, which I can convert to latitude-longitude easily enough with SQL Server 2008. However I need to convert a latitude-longitude to X and Y, which don't seem to be as easy.

Its for small area in Queensland Australia. I can create a point using the geography type but is there an easier way to calculate the X and Y coordinates of that point from SQL Server?

Regards

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx